# Triggering events in AngularJS that bubble up the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I know there a `triggerHandler()` equivalent of jQuery in AngularJS but there is no `trigger()` equivalent of jQuery for AngularJS. Is this due to some ideological difference or just to keep jQLite as slim as possible?

Also, how do I best implement jQuery's `trigger()`?
I tried this [link](http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html), but found it a difficult to understand.
I would appreciate if someone could help me emulate `.trigger()` of jQuery using vanilla Javascript the AngularJS way?